# How to make Android layout like marksheets?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have no idea how to make this, please help

I want to make a markshit layout view in android xml.
How could i make it, can i use ListView to make semester dynamic..

```
            sem 1    sem 2    sem 3.... Total
 math          20       25      22        67
 science       18       22      24        64
 english       18       22      24        64
 physical      20       25      22        67

 Total         76       94      92        262
```

Comment: Yes, use listview for it.

Comment: do you get data from webservice as JSON?

Comment: yes I have got data from webservice by JSON, problem in representation of data and layout.

Comment: Check my answer and comment if you need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this layout, iam using two table layouts. One for header and one for data.
data is wrapped in scrollview, so the header will be fixed and data can be scrolled. Also i have a hidden row for every row, where is store the headertext or datatext which ever is long. By doing this, we can make columns populate equally. otherwise we may end up in wrong representation of data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mark_sheet);

            try {
                DisplayMarkSheet(new JSONObject(ReturnJsonData()));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String ReturnJsonData() {

            return "{\"SemisterData\":" +
            //Specify your columns here
            "{\"Columns\":" +
                "[" +
                    "{\"ColumnName\":\"\"}," + //This column is intentionally blank. First Row, First Column will be blank
                    "{\"ColumnName\":\"Semister1\"}," +
                    "{\"ColumnName\":\"Semister2\"}," +
                    "{\"ColumnName\":\"Semister3\"}," +
                    "{\"ColumnName\":\"Semister4\"}," +
                    "{\"ColumnName\":\"Semister5\"}]," +
            "\"FooterRows\":" +
                "[" +
                    "{\"Cells\":" +
                        "[" +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"Total\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"160\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"200\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"240\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"300\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"340\"}]}]," +
            "\"Rows\":" + //One row for each subject, Rows will have cells with data
                "[" +
                    "{\"Cells\":" +
                        "[" +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"Maths\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"40\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"50\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"60\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"70\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"80\"}]}," +

                    "{\"Cells\":" +
                        "[" +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"Science\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"40\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"50\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"60\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"70\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"80\"}]}," +
                    "{\"Cells\":" +
                        "[" +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"English\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"40\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"50\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"60\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"70\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"80\"}]}," +
                    "{\"Cells\":" +
                        "[" +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"Physics\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"40\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"50\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"60\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"70\"}," +
                            "{\"CellValue\":\"80\"}]}]}}";
        }

        public TextView GetHeaderTextView(String HeaderText) {
            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(HeaderText);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            title.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            return title;
        }

        public TextView GetHeaderTextViewHidden(String HeaderText) {
            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(HeaderText);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A9A9A9"));
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            // title.setTextAppearance(context, color.RowText);
            title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            title.setHeight(0);
            title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            return title;
        }

        public TextView GetItemTextView(String ItemText, String ColumnAlign) {
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setText(ItemText);

            if (ColumnAlign.equals("L"))
                text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            else if (ColumnAlign.equals("R"))
                text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            else if (ColumnAlign.equals("C"))
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            // text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
            // R.drawable.next_image, 0);
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            return text;
        }

        public static TextView GetItemTextViewHidden(Context context, String ItemText, String ColumnAlign) {
            TextView text = new TextView(context);
            text.setText(ItemText);
            if (ColumnAlign.equals("L"))
                text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            else if (ColumnAlign.equals("R"))
                text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            else if (ColumnAlign.equals("C"))
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            text.setHeight(0);
            text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            return text;
        }

        public void DisplayMarkSheet(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
            TableLayout headerTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
            TableLayout dataTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

            headerTable.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            dataTable.setStretchAllColumns(true);

            TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow invisibleHeaderRow = new TableRow(this);

            JSONArray columnsArray = json.getJSONObject("SemisterData").getJSONArray("Columns");
            JSONArray rowsArray = json.getJSONObject("SemisterData").getJSONArray("Rows");
            JSONArray footerArray = json.getJSONObject("SemisterData").getJSONArray("FooterRows");

            // Create header row and add Columns
            if (json.getJSONObject("SemisterData").isNull("Columns") == false) {
                headerRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                for (int i = 0; i <= columnsArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    headerRow.addView(GetHeaderTextView(columnsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ColumnName")));
                    invisibleHeaderRow.addView(GetHeaderTextViewHidden(columnsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ColumnName")));
                }
                headerTable.addView(headerRow);
                headerTable.addView(invisibleHeaderRow);
            }

            // Create data row and add data
            String headerText = "";
            String rowText;
            if (json.getJSONObject("SemisterData").isNull("Rows") == false) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= rowsArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    TableRow dataRow = new TableRow(this);
                    TableRow invisibledataRow = new TableRow(this);

                    dataRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    int cellsLength = 0;
                    if (rowsArray.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Cells") == false)

                    {
                        cellsLength = rowsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").length();
                        for (int k = 0; k <= cellsLength - 1; k++) {

                            dataRow.addView(GetItemTextView(rowsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").getJSONObject(k).getString("CellValue"), "C"));
                            rowText = rowsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").getJSONObject(k).getString("CellValue");

                            headerText = (String) ((TextView) invisibleHeaderRow.getChildAt(k)).getText();
                            if (headerText.length() > rowText.length())
                                invisibledataRow.addView(GetItemTextViewHidden(this, headerText, "C"));
                            else {
                                invisibledataRow.addView(GetItemTextViewHidden(this, rowsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").getJSONObject(k).getString("CellValue"), "C"));
                                ((TextView) invisibleHeaderRow.getChildAt(k)).setText(rowText);
                            }

                        }
                        dataRow.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
                        dataTable.addView(dataRow);
                        dataTable.addView(invisibledataRow);
                    }
                }

            }

            // Create footer row and populate data
            if (json.getJSONObject("SemisterData").isNull("FooterRows") == false) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= footerArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    TableRow footerRow = new TableRow(this);
                    footerRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    if (footerArray.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Cells") == false) {
                        for (int k = 0; k <= footerArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").length() - 1; k++) {
                            footerRow.addView(GetItemTextView(footerArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").getJSONObject(k).getString("CellValue"), "C"));
                            footerRow.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                            if (headerText.length() < footerArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").getJSONObject(k).getString("CellValue").length())
                                ((TextView) invisibleHeaderRow.getChildAt(k)).setText(footerArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Cells").getJSONObject(k).getString("CellValue"));
                        }
                        dataTable.addView(footerRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

XML File

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/WidgetsHSV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/GridLL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >
        </TableLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/table_scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/maintable"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>]
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridLayout` for this or `LinearLayout`

If you are using `GridLayout` then push an empty view for position 0 and position 1,2,3,4,5... column will contain your semester heading and last column index will be Total

now next row's first element will be your subject header and same for every for

you have to arrange your model accordingly to achieve proper data representation

If you are using `LinearLlayout` then your Layout will be in xml using `LinearLayout` weightSum and weigh property